# How to keep Docker name resolution when HTML from NGINX try to consume WebAPI service in Docker Compose?

Tags: .net, docker, nginx, docker-compose, blazor

I'm orchestrating the **staging** environment through `docker-compose`, and expect to use the services name to address internal requests (Docker DNS).

The system consists of:

- A MSSQL (*internal access only*)
- A RabbitMQ (*external access just for management in port `15672`*)
- Some Worker Services (AMQP) (*internal access only*)
- A WebAPI BFF (HTTP) (*internal access only*)
- A WASM WebAPP (HTML) in **NGINX** as Web Server (*external access only*)

To handle this two networks were defined in docker-compose:

```yaml
networks:
  internal:
    name: internal
    driver: bridge
  external:
    name: external
    external: true
```

For MSSQL, RabbitMQ, Worker Services, and WebAPI only the internal network was defined. For WebAPP, both networks were defined:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:

  mssql:
    container_name: mssql
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    ports:
      - "1433" #internal access only
    networks:
      - internal

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "5672" #internal access only
      - "15672:15672" #external access via http://localhost:15672
    networks:
      - internal

  shoppingcart:
    image: shoppingcart
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./src/Services/ShoppingCart/WorkerService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT: Staging #Environment 
    depends_on:
      mssql:
        condition: service_started
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - internal

  webapi:
    image: webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./src/Web/WebAPI/Dockerfile
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://*:5000
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging #Environment
    ports:
      - "5000" #internal access only
    networks:
      - internal        

  webapp:
    image: webapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./src/Web/WebAPP/Dockerfile
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging #Environment
    ports:
      - "8080:80" #external access via http://localhost:8080
    depends_on:
      webapi:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - internal
      - external

networks:
  internal:
    name: internal
    driver: bridge
  external:
    name: external
    external: true
```

About **WebAPP** settings by environment, for **WebAPI** consumption:

*Development*

```json
{
  "HttpClientOptions": {
    "BaseAddress": "http://localhost:5000/"
  }
}
```

*Staging*

```json
{
  "HttpClientOptions": {
    "BaseAddress": "http://webapi:5000/"
  }
}
```

All other services interact by name, only the WebAPP on NGINX does not.

The question is: **How keep Docker name resolution (DNS) when NGINX consumes another service in the same network?**

One more step has been taken to try to solve this. Another NGINX service just for reverse proxy was created and configured to use Docker resolver (127.0.0.11):

```
user nginx;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
            
        location / {
            set $docker_host "webapp";
            proxy_pass http://$docker_host:80;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is comprehension. The WebAPP is a WASM application, which means that it's running on the client-side and obviously far away from the Docker internal network.